# Set the dropdownheight for a combobox c# CF3.5

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

Is there a way to set the dropdownheight for a combobox in CF3.5? There is no such property in CF and I can't seem to do it on Design either. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

//-------------------------------------------------------------Update---------------------------------------------------------//

```
    [DllImport("coredll.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct RECT
    {
        public int left, top, right, bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct COMBOBOXINFO
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public RECT rcItem;
        public RECT rcButton;
        public int stateButton;
        public IntPtr hwndCombo;
        public IntPtr hwndItem;
        public IntPtr hwndList;
    }

    public static IntPtr IntPtrAlloc<T>(T param)
    {
        IntPtr retval = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(param));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(param, retval, false);
        return retval;
    }

    COMBOBOXINFO cbi = new COMBOBOXINFO();
    IntPtr cbiPointer = IntPtrAlloc(cbi);
    SendMessage(comboBox1.Handle, CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO, IntPtr.Zero, cbi);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself but I believe it can be done.
override the combobox's OnHandleCreated, use pinvoke to call SendMessage with CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO (0x0162) which will return with a Comboboxinfo struct containing a handle to the dropdown list control, store the handle to your dropdown list. When you want to update the dropdown height pinvoke SetWindowPos using the handle to your dropdown list and your desired height.

Comment: Hi, I didn't follow-up with this post last time because I found another way to overcome this matter. Now, I want to test your suggestion, but I cannot seem to find a way to pass the combo box struct in SendMessage to be filled up with the information.

I have added some sample snippet, hope you can correct me on that, thanks.